# Angular 2 - Http Post returning undefined error

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am putting together an admin function to create a user. Part of the creation of the user is to provide them access to certain databases.

In the code, I am sending an http post to my web api to create the user. Upon successful creation, I will then add the user-database bindings.

```
private createUserDatabases(createdUser: Users) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(createdUser));
        if (this.isSuperAdmin && this.newUserDatabases.length > 0) {    
            var newUserDbs: UserDatabase[] = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < this.newUserDatabases.length; i++) {                
                var newUserDatabase = new UserDatabase();                            
                newUserDatabase.database_Id = this.newUserDatabases[i].id;
                newUserDatabase.user_Id = createdUser.id;
                newUserDbs.push(newUserDatabase);
                //console.log("Getting ready to create");
                //this.usersService.addUserToDatabase(newUserDatabase);
                //    .subscribe(
                //    data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)),
                //    error => {
                //        this.alertService.error(error._body);
                //        console.log("userDb" + error._body);
                //    }
                //);
            }

            console.log(newUserDbs);
            return this.usersService.addUserToDatabase(newUserDbs);

            //this.isOpened = false;
        }    
    }    
onSubmit() {   
            var createdUser: Users;
            this.usersService.create(this.user)
                .do(u => createdUser = u)
                .flatMap(u => {                
                    return this.createUserDatabases(u);
                })
                .subscribe(
                data => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    this.loadAllUsers();
                    this.isOpened = false;
                },
                error => {
                    this.alertService.error(error._body);
                    console.log(error._body);
                }
              )            
        }
```

The database bindings are being sent as an array of objects (string, string). I have tried this as individual calls per selected database, as well as a single call with all selected databases.

Here is the service

```
   create(newUser: Users) {
        return this.http.post(this.config.apiUrl + '/api/accounts/create', JSON.stringify(newUser), this.jwt())
            .map((response: any) => response.json());
    }


    addUserToDatabase(newUserToDatabases: UserDatabase[]) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(newUserToDatabases));
        return this.http.post(this.config.apiUrl + '/api/userdatabases/create', JSON.stringify(newUserToDatabases), this.jwt())
            .map((response: any) => response.json());
    }
```

Everything is completing as desired and neither of the requests are returning errors, however, I am receiving an undefined error and not making it to the data => portion of subscribe. I have found many articles and plunkrs that seem to imply this setup should work.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: It is just showing undefined

Answer (score 1):

below your map code  use

```
.catch((error)=> {
 return Observable throw(error)
 };
```

Comment: may be you are expecting something in observable so Observable should be return see above code

Comment: You were onto something! I realized it was because I was mapping a JSON response despite the webapi only replying OK(); I removed the .map and that fixed it.